# Calling a function from another file fails

Tags: go

I have a file `routes.go`

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func initializeRoutes() {
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(
            http.StatusOK,
            "index.html",
            gin.H{
                "title": "Home Page",
            },
        )
    })
}
```

and `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var router *gin.Engine

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    initializeRoutes()
    router.Run()
}
```

I have tried running them with the *.go and go run main.go routes.go, I still for some reason get a runtime error. what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the full error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x914518]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.initializeRoutes()
        C:/Users/tomuk/go/src/webapp/routes.go:10 +0x58
main.main()
        C:/Users/tomuk/go/src/webapp/main.go:16 +0x51
```

Comment: If it's a runtime error, then it's not a problem calling a function from another file since you were able to compile the program. Show the actual error that you're getting and what you do to get it.

Comment: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x914518]

Comment: If you have a panic, you have a stack trace. Update the question with the output and show where in your code it's panicking.

Comment: i updated my post, does that help?

Comment: This is a runtime error, so has nothing to do with multiple files. The panic is on `routes.go:10` -- what is that? (the files you pasted here don't line up with your real line numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with calling a function from another file. The problem is this line:

```
router := gin.Default()
```

This creates a new *local* variable called `router`, and intializes it, leaving the global `router` variable still uninitialized (`nil`). So when `initializeRoutes` tries to call the global `routes` variable, it panics because it's trying to dereference a `nil` variable (as the error states).

Change the line in `main` to:

```
router = gin.Default()
```

To initialize the global variable instead of creating a new variable, and that should resolve the issue.